# JSON Object Parsing for Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

Basically I have this basic json file.

```
{
 "email":"theoaristi53@gmail.com",
 "name":"Theo Tziomakas"
}
```

which is located it a server as it looks. Now I want to get it from there back in Android phone.

```
I use this snippet but I get a null for both email and name.


        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
        Person p = new Person();
        jsonObject.put("email",p.getEmail());
        jsonObject.put("name",p.getName());
```

I am going to fetch the data from the server using the Volley libray.

```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   public static final String BASE_URL =  
  "http://test.lovenaxos.com/testing.json";
   public List<Person> personList;
   public TextView output;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    requestData("http://test.lovenaxos.com/testing.json");

}

public void requestData(String url){
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    personList = JsonParser.parseFeed(response);
                    updateData();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {



        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
            });
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(request);
}

protected void updateData(){
    if(personList!=null){
       for(Person p : personList){
           output.append(p.getName() + "\n");
       }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you get anything from p.getEmail()?Can you add some more code.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but why are you using the put method to extract data from the JSONObject ? Or are you trying to modify the data?

Comment: I have more code now so you can see better. Simply I want to fetch that data from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `put(..)` use `getString(.)`:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
String email = jsonObject.getString("email");
String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
```